# Get non matching record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two views. Both the views have most of the columns same. View1 has 20 columns and View2 has 22 columns. View2 has 20 columns same as View1.
Now I want a query to find out if the data in these common 20 columns is the same or not and if not I would like to get those records

View1

```
Columns FN  LN  EmpID
    a   b   1
    c   d   2
```

View2

```
Columns FN  LN  EmpID
    a   b   1
    c   b   2
```

I want a query where I can check if there is any mismatch in column values  between View1 and View2 and if there is a mismatch than return that record. Like the query should return View2's second record because it does not match with View1 second record

Comment: What is your question here? You've stated what you want to do but not asked anything. What have you tried? If you haven't tried please do. If you have, why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu, I am new to sql and the whole point of asking this question is that how shall I write a SQL query to get the expected result mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Jay SO is designed to assist you when you get stuck after having done your own research, which might include other tutorials and online documentation. Its not a place to come for someone to write your code for you - you're expected to do the heavy lifting and then SO can assist you.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, But I am not asking how  to write a select, insert or update commands, or a simple inner join, left outer  join, right outer join.

Comment: "But I am not asking how to write a select, insert or update commands".  So what are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXCEPT instead of having to JOIN against all of the columns. This will give you everything from View1 that is not matched in View2:

```
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], [Col5]
FROM VIEW1
EXCEPT
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], [Col5]
FROM VIEW2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from view1 a , view2 b
where a.Columns = b.Columns
having ( a.FN  <> b.FN  or a.LN  <> b.LN  or a.EmpID <> b.EmpID )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.